# A limit problem..

Tags: real-analysis

Find the limits
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n \left( 1- \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \log \left(2+\cos\left( \frac{x}{n}\right)\right)\, dx$$

Don't know how to deal with $\cos(x/n)$. Can anyone give me some hints? Many Thanks!

Comment: Check Lebesgue domainated convergence theorem.

Comment: Check this [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616242/a-question-based-on-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem).

Comment: how to find the dominated function for this integrad? seems like $e^{-x}$ doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you let $n$ go to $\infty$ then $\frac{x}{n}$ becomes zero. Secondly we know a lot about $\cos$, it is monotonic on $[0,1]$ thirdly we know a lot about $\log(y)$ it is monotonic everywere so the bigger $y$ the bigger is $\log(y)$ and it's positive after 1.

So knowing that we can say:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_0^n \left( 1- \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \log \Bigg(2+\underbrace{\cos\left( \frac{x}{n}\right)}_{\le 1}\Bigg)\  \text{d}x\le \lim_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_0^n \left( 1- \frac{x}{n}\right)^n \log(3)\ \text{d}x $$

Hopefully that solves your issue!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I thought this problem could be solved by dominated convergence theorem at first but I cannot find the dominated function. So do you have any idea by using LDCT for this problem? I solved it by absolutely continuity and monotone convergence theorem, Which was a little bit complicated. So I was wondering if there would be a simple way.